# Is there any memory limitation for saving .mp3 data to iOS device using iOS application

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios4, nsfilemanager

I am developing an application, that has a module downloading MP3 files from a server and save the last 5 downloads to iOS device. For this I am using NSFileManager and document directory (each downloads has 40MB to 60MB). Now I am facing some issues, that is four downloads save successfully and during the 5th download time the application automatically delete the first downloads and some time the app shows crashes.

My question is, is there any memory limitation for save large file (above 500MB) to iOS device? If any limitation, what is the maximum size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge Apple uses HFS Plus file system, and it can have max file size up to 8 exabyte

1 EB = 1000000000000000000B = 1018 bytes = 1000000000gigabytes = 1000000terabytes

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for your replay.Could you give some more explanation about your answer?

Comment: basically max storage provided in iOS devices is 64 GB, so technically there is no file size limit. As you can create file up to 1 EG in HFS Plus, which is larger then 64 GB.